# Make else statement perform the opposite of the if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I have spaces being equal to 2. However, I want my else statement to execute when spaces does not equal 2 (whether that's more than 2 or less than 2).

```
if (spaces1.length() == ((spaces * 2) - 1)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces1.length(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            numGuessed = 0;
            if (Character.isDigit(spaces1.charAt(i))) {
                numGuessed = Integer.parseInt(spaces1.substring(i, i + 1));
                correctSpace = true;
            } else {
                correctSpace = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an editor that auto-formats your code for indentations, that'll help you spot bugs like this.

You have an extra curly bracket that closes the main `if` statement (before `numGuessed = numGuessed - 1`. The `else` statement that you mentioned is actually an `else` for the external `if` (the `difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("h")` one).